# Check Ionic 2 Radio Button Programmatically using TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Lets say I have the following list:

```
<ion-list radio-group [(ngModel)]="autoManufacturers">
  <ion-list-header>
    Auto Manufacturers
  </ion-list-header>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Cord</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="cord"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Duesenberg</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="duesenberg"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Hudson</ion-label>
    <ion-radio value="hudson"></ion-radio>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Depending upon what value I get from the database, I want to check the item in the list. Lets say if I get value 'cord' then item 2 should displayed as selected item. How can I achieve this using TypeScript?

Comment: can you update with your json response

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you're binding the radio group to the `autoManufacturers` property from your Component, the only thing you need to do is assigning to that property the value you get from the database:

```
// somewhere in your code
this.autoManufacturers = valueFromDataBase; // where valueFromDataBase === 'cord'
```

By doing that, the option with the *cord* value will be selected automatically.

Comment: What if the value is an object?

Comment: In that case, you could use the `id` of that object (and also use the `id` in the `value` property from the view) @filippo